# A word for swings, slides, seats, seesaws, etc

Tags: word-request, vocabulary, phrase-request

I'm looking for a word for the things at a place where children play on Swings, Slides, Seesaws, Climbing Frames, etc. Is there a common word in English for these in general? Like in Indian languages, we say, "jhoolay झूले (plural)". After googling for a while, I could only get the phrase "outdoor toys". I don't think it's that suitable word which I'm looking for or it may be. The word referring to those things in general should be able to be used in such sentences: Our children are playing on/at/with the _____ (plural noun). There are ____ (plural noun) in that park.

Comment: Also, you play "at" a playground. You play "on" the equipment. "What did you do at the playground?"
"I went on the slide, and I went on the swings, and I went on the seesaw!" By the way, I love how the OP called something "a climbing frame." I think we might call that a jungle gym.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would refer to that as "playground equipment".

In regards to your example sentences:

For the first, I would just specify what specific piece of equipment ("Our children are playing on the slide") or just speak in a generalization ("Our children are playing at the playground").

For the second, I would say "There is a lot of playground equipment at that park".

Answer (score 9):

In American English, there is a *swing set*, which is the frame with several swings and can include an attached seesaw and/or slide. Families might have one in their back yard. And a park might have a larger version.

But a park might also have several stand alone seesaws, slides, etc., which I would just call *[playground equipment](https://www.google.com/?sbntsp=1&query=playground%20equipment%20for%20schools&safe=active&key=23898278c1850f536d688db3614128a0)*.

But both adults and kids will talk about **playgrounds** (the 'ground' at a park on which kids play), and it is assumed that a *playground* includes such equipment.

> Do you wanna go play on the playground?
>
> No, that playground is stupid. All the swings are broken.
>
> Okay, then let's go to the other park—it has a great playground!

(Meaning: the 'play equipment' and 'play structures' at this second park are outstanding and fun.)

Other words besides *playground equipment* include *park and play structures* and *park and play systems*. These are mostly technical words. Your average American will just say *playground*. They might mention specific things, such as the swings, slides, seesaws, humongous outdoor play house, which certain parks and/or playgrounds may have.

Comment: +1 - If I told my daughter we were going to a _playground_ and upon arrival she found there was no _playground equipment_ she would be very disappointed, and declare "this is just a boring _field._  (Or _playfield_.)

Answer (score 3):

I take it that you want a [hypernym](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hypernym) of "the things at a place where children play on Swings, Slides, Seesaws, Climbing Frames, etc." As mentioned in other answers, you can use *playground equipment*. I'd like to add another alternative: ***recreational equipment***.

Wikipedia uses this term on the page [Playground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playground):

> Modern playgrounds often have recreational equipment such as the seesaw, merry-go-round, swingset, slide, jungle gym, chin-up bars, sandbox, spring rider, trapeze rings, playhouses, and mazes, many of which help children develop physical coordination, strength, and flexibility, as well as providing recreation and enjoyment. Common in modern playgrounds are *play structures* that link many different pieces of equipment.

Note that *equipment*, like *furniture*, is normally used as an uncountable noun.

Comment: Play structures - that's what I remember them being called when I was a school kid.

Answer (score 1):

English has no exact translation or hypernym for جھولے , so I suggest we use "rides" 
Like the Entry in Oxford Dictionary (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ride) (**2A roller coaster, roundabout, or other amusement ridden at a fair or amusement park.**) (**Example from the same source:** ‘When I was a kid I loved the rides at amusements parks - the Zipper, the Swings, the Polar Express and even those cheesy haunted houses.’)

Comment: I feel this is a good answer for amusement parks, but the same words don't apply to a children's playground at a standard family/recreational park.

Answer (score -1):

You can say playground apparatus, recreational devices, but I think the word ***'Rides'*** is more appropriate.

This amusement park/playground has all kinds of rides.

[OALD entry says:](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/ride_2)

> rides: *a large machine at a funfair or amusement park that you ride on for fun or excitement; an occasion when you go on one of these.*

Comment: झूले  actually means 'swing' but here, the OP wants to describe them **all** in general. So, here, it means 'rides'. +1 Added definition.

Comment: I would normally associate _rides_ with an amusement park's mechanical swings, like [these](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbm=isch&q=%22riding+the+swings%22), not with swinging on playground equipment, like [this](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbm=isch&q=swinging+on+the+equipment).

Comment: Maulik, I think we are wrong; I agree with @J.R.

Comment: @Khan - "wrong" is such a strong word; I'd feel more comfortable saying "unusual" or "less common." If you look hard enough, you can find a few sources where "rides on the playground" is used in this context. A term like that could be regional, too. I found a sentence published in _The New Indian Express_ which began: _When he was told to perch on one of the rides on the playground..._

Answer (score -2):

The correct word is **RIDES**

It combines all types of playground equipment.

Comment: [Amusement parks](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/amusement+park) aren't the same thing as [playgrounds](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/playground). Amusement parks have "rides", playgrounds have "equipment". Also this duplicates Khan's answer, but with less detail.

Comment: In future, I'd recommend also adding references (such as a link to a dictionary definition) when stating the meaning of a word or how appropriate it is.